# Getting error while accessing excel data using apache POI and java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a function which takes Excel Path and Sheet Name and returns int value of number of rows but when i tried to run it, it gives following error. I'm new to java so it might be because im too stupid lol.

my system:

1. Netbeans 8.2
2. jdk 1.8
3. Apache poi-src-4.1.2-20200217
4. Kubuntu Latest

my input:

1. ExcelPath:/media/bigdata/Downloads/text2.xls
2. SheetName:Sheet1

Code:

```
package com.test.system;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class NewClass {

 private static FileInputStream fis;
 private static FileOutputStream fileOut;
 private static XSSFWorkbook wb;
 private static XSSFSheet sh;
 private static XSSFCell cell;
 private static XSSFRow row;
 private static XSSFCellStyle cellstyle;
 private static XSSFColor mycolor;

 public static int setExcelFile(String ExcelPath,String SheetName) throws Exception
 { 
    int noOfRows = -1;
    try{  
       File f = new File(ExcelPath);
       if(!f.exists()){
          System.out.println("File doesn't exist.");
        }  
       else{
            fis=new FileInputStream(ExcelPath);
            System.out.println(fis);
            wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sh = wb.getSheet(SheetName);
            //sh = wb.getSheetAt(0); //0 - index of 1st sheet
            if (sh == null)
            {
                sh = wb.createSheet(SheetName);
            }
       }
       noOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum();  
     }catch (IOException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
return (noOfRows);
 }

}
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
    at com.test.system.NewClass.setExcelFile(NewClass.java:45)
    at com.test.system.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more
```

I tried everything but still no success.

Comment: Looks like you need to [add all the Apache POI dependencies to your runtime classpath](http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components), what happens when you have done that?

Comment: It lacks `xmlbeans` which is a prerequisite of either `poi-ooxml-schemas` or `ooxml-schemas`. Either `poi-ooxml-schemas` or `ooxml-schemas` is needed from the `XSSF` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement you should write

fis=new FileInputStream(f);

instead of

fis=new FileInputStream(ExcelPath);

and you cannot use: System.out.println(fis);  //It Won't Work

Comment: Still getting same result. exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException